# Отключение экрана по времени

Tags: linux, shell

Необходимо отключение экрана при бездействии n времени.
Отключение экрана выполняется при помощи  /sys/class/backlight...

А где в системе посмотреть и изменить время до отключения, используя консоль?

Answer (score 2):

например, при наличии работающего x-сервера, можно воспользоваться программой `xset`.

текущее состояние dpms (display power management signaling):

```
$ xset q | tail -n 4
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

отключить/включить dpms можно так:

```
$ xset -dpms
$ xset +dpms
```

про отключенный dpms программа `xset` с параметром `q` так и напишет:

```
$ xset q | tail -n 1
  DPMS is Disabled
```

изменить время (в секундах) для standby, suspend и off (т.е., отключения питания монитора), можно так:

```
$ xset dpms 100 200 300
```

проверка:

```
$ xset q | tail -n 4
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 100    Suspend: 200    Off: 300
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

подробнее можно прочитать в `man xset`.

---

при отсутствии работающего x-сервера можно воспользоваться программой `setterm`. в частности, полезными будут опции: `--blank`, `--powersave`, `--powerdown` (с нужными параметрами).

подробнее можно прочитать в `man setterm`.

Comment: Иксов нет. Нужно добраться через систему.

Comment: @Sebefour, дополнил ответ.

Comment: setterm тоже нет. Доставить возможности не имею.

Comment: @Sebefour. сочувствую.