# 2 монитора - не уходят в сон

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, monitor

Помогите решить проблему - 2 монитора, подключенных через hdmi и dvi порты, не уходят в сон.
Подключенные по отдельности и к любому из портов - уходят в сон нормально, а вот вместе не хотят.

Проявляется это так - через заданное время не уходят в сон, а если выключаю принудительно, `xset dpms force off` - мониторы гаснут и тут же просыпаются.
Софтовое отключение одного из мониторов (напр., `xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off`) проблему не решает, приходится физически отключать, выдергивать видеокабель.

OS - Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa (Ubuntu 20.04 focal)
Видеокарта - AMD Radeon RX550/550

Как побороть проблему?

P.S. Ах, да - в винде нормально отключаются) Т.е. проблема софтовая

**$ hwinfo --monitor --short**

```
VIEWSONIC VX3276-QHD
DELL U2412M
```

**$ xset q**

```
Keyboard Control:  
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, как именуются ваши 2 монитора.

Comment: вывод `$ xset q` явно не помешал бы. пожалуйста, приложите его (текстом, естественно), нажав [edit].

Comment: Добавил инфо о мониторах

Comment: вот и ответ: `Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0`. у вас просто не включено ничего — все таймауты выставлены в ноль. попробуйте задать нужным таймаутам значения. с помощью xset (см. `$ man xset`). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479815/178576

Comment: Но при подключенном одном мониторе то же самое показывает и, тем не менее, монитор засыпает. Но, ок попробую покапаться с xset

Comment: Выставил $ xset dpms 100 200 300
Не помогло, все равно не уходит в сон (через xset dpms force off попробовал)

Comment: Для теста выставил по 10 секунд - xset dpms 10 10 10.
Один монитор - нормально засыпает, подключаю второй - мониторы засыпают и тут же просыпаются.
Интересный глюк при xset dpms 10 20 30 - мониторы в цикл уходят (если мышкой/клавой не прервать), засыпают-просыпаются и так по кругу)

Comment: значит, какой-то процесс их «будит». первый подозреваемый — т.н. «драйвер» видеокарты. следующий — что-нибудь из набора de (desktop environment).