# Ubuntu 20.04 не выключается экран после простоя

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

После простоя компьютера, экран не выключается. Нашел решение: `xset dpms 0 0 15`. Через 15 секунд экран действительно гаснет, но тут же сразу включается обратно.

`xset dpms q` выводит:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 15
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Ubuntu 20.04. Gnome 3.36.9

Пробовал закрывать все программы, вдруг какая-то не дает это сделать. Не помогло.

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: А если просто поискать что-нибудь в настройках электропитания GNOME на эту тему? У меня его настройки вполне работали и всё выключалось

Comment: Электропитание > Выключение экрана 5 минут. Через 5 минут не выключается - точнее также выключается и сразу включается

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240174/2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2177263_1240174