# Выключается монитор при бездействии в Xubuntu

Tags: linux, xubuntu

Меня давно преследует такая беда в Xubuntu, которая началась кажется в 19.04. Сейчас у меня 20.04. Обновляться до 21.04 лень, хотя я повредил целостность системы в попытках исправить этот баг, так что наверное придётся.

Изначально меня не устраивало автоотключение монитора при бездействии. Когда я смотрю фильм, монитор выключается. Эта фича пытается быть умной и монитор вроде как не выключается при просмотре ютуба через фаерфокс и видео через некоторые плееры, но далеко не все плееры и браузеры поддерживаются.

Когда я пытался увеличить время бездействия, там в настройках было 2 пункта отвечающих за время для монитора. Я так и не понял, чем они отличаются. Выкрутил до максимума оба и это не помогло! Монитор по-прежнему вырубался через 10 минут.

Тогда у меня лопнуло терпение, я открыл синаптик, вбил в поиск "power" и удалил все пакеты, в описании которых были намёки на автоматическое управление питанием. После чего все настройки, связанные с уходом в сон, гибернацией и отключением монитора исчезли, но монитор выключается.

Я гуглил всё что мог, пытался отключать различные сервисы и ничего не помогло. Например, ничего из [этого вопроса](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep) не помогает.

```
xset s noexpose
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms
```

Тоже не помогло.

UPD: Только что установил по новой `xfce4-power-manager`, настроил его и вроде бы как проблема решена! Даже не знаю, почему раньше он выделывался. Честно говоря, мне не нравится то что для **удаления** функционала приходится **устанавливать** софт, да ещё и в автозапуск, но других вариантов у меня нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479805/178576